# 2005 web service that I cannot consume in 3.5 app

Tags: service, asmx

When I look at the .asmx page in the browser I see:
The following operations are supported. For a formal definition, please review the Service Description.

AcceptCaseInformation

ClearServiceErrors

CreateBatch

GetBookingsOnIndictment

GetCaseInformation

GetCasesForJacket

When I reference the asmx file in my project I do not see these web methods.  I see the complete set of methods in the Reference.cs.
   JSSTester.GrandJuryService.GetBookingsOnIndictmentRequest
   JSSTester.GrandJuryService.GetBookingsOnIndictmentRequestBody
   JSSTester.GrandJuryService.GetBookingsOnIndictmentResponse

What am I not setting to allow me to see the WebMethods for that asmx page?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm following your process, you're using the "Add Service Reference" option through your project in Visual Studio.

By default, the 3.5 apps want to leverage the newer WCF framework, which doesn't use the older web service architecture found in your ASMX style pages. However, you can still add the older services, it just takes a little more work.

When this dialog opens up, there should be a button at the bottom at the page that says "Add Web Reference." Click this button and it should expose the "legacy" methods that are available.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up an looking for the advanced button and going from there.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it should not be necessary to use the "Advanced" button and to revert to a Web Reference. In general, any standard web service created using VS2005 should be consumable via a Service Reference with no trouble at all.

Is your service created using WSE? Does it contain references to `Microsoft.Web.Services3`? In that case, you don't have a standard VS2005 web service - you have an obsolete WSE service, and you will need to look more closely to see what the problem is.